# How to invoke one method of require module in html tag line

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs

I have to invoke require module in html tag line.Also it is deprecate.I think it is need when html tag dynamic generated.

The require module:

```
define('index',['jquery','common','stat'],function($,common,stat){
return{
    rankList:function(name){
        stat.ranklist(name,function(data){
            console.log('invoked...');

        });
    }
}
```

});

The html tag lines:

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
                <li class="active"><a href="#task" data-toggle="tab" onclick="rankListCall.rank('asCount')"><em><strong>任务量大咖</strong></em></a></li>
                <li><a href="#income" data-toggle="tab" onclick="rankListCall.rank('totalAmount')"><em><strong>收入大咖</strong></em></a></li>
                <li><a href="#right" data-toggle="tab" onclick="rankListCall.rank('accurateRate')"><em><strong>准确大咖</strong></em></a></li>
            </ul>
```

Load script in html:

```
<script type='text/javascript'  src="http://cdn.staticfile.org/require-jquery/0.25.0/require-jquery.js"></script>
```

`<script type='text/javascript'  src="../../static/js/app.min.js"></script>`

The javascript I tried in html :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rankListCall=(function(){
    var index=require(['index']);
    return{
        rank:function(name){
            index.rankList(name);
        }
   }
})();
```

I got the script error in line

`index.rankList(name);`

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: I don't know the proper way, but this could be possible `onclick = somefunction()` & `function somefunction(){index.rankList(name)}`

Comment: The same error occured.I try write this way.it is ok,but I this it is injudicial.function rank(name){
        require(['index'],function(index){
            index.rankList(name);
        })
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most require modules won't export their objects to the global namespace (jQuery is a notorious exception to this, but let's pretend it's not). Therefore, you should try to handle your functions and behaviors inside of the require call. No matter how much you export and include stuff, the DOM won't be able to "see" your functions unless you export them as (for example) `window.rankList`, but that's like defeating require's purpose.

This is what I'd do to have access both to the dom and the stat function.

```
define(['jquery','common','stat'],function(jQuery,common,stat){

    jQuery(document).on('click','.rankListCall',function() {
        var name=jQuery(this).data('name');
        stat.ranklist(name,function(data){
            console.log('invoked...',name,data);
        });
    });
});
```

and yout html code

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#task" data-toggle="tab" class="rankListCall" data-name="asCount"><em><strong>任务量大咖</strong></em></a></li>
    <li><a href="#income" data-toggle="tab" class="rankListCall" data-name="totalAmount"><em><strong>收入大咖</strong></em></a></li>
    <li><a href="#right" data-toggle="tab" class="rankListCall" data-name="accurateRate"><em><strong>准确大咖</strong></em></a></li>
</ul>
```

instead of trying to export your functions to the global namespace, try to keep the logic separate from the DOM. That way you can handle both functions and behaviors inside the require section. In this case I added a class and a data attribute to your elements to allow jQuery to delegate events on them.